# How do I create a makefile rule to run astyle?

Tags: formatting, makefile, astyle

I'd like to create a makefile rule to run astyle on any writable source files. Currently, I have a rule like the following:

```
style:
  find . -perm -200 -regex ".*[.][CHch]p*" -exec astyle --suffix=none --style=ansi --convert-tabs "{}" \;
```

This rule basically works but doesn't seem to be the *make* way of doing things.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better. To do a regex search you'd have to delegate to the shell and `sed` or something, which wouldn't be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of source files (or can create them with the shell function), something like:

```
style : $(SOURCES:.cpp=.astyle-check-stamp)
    astyle $(ASTYLEFLAGS) $< && touch $@
```

would be the make-style. It would re-check each changed source file with astyle and skipped already checked files.